# Замена блоков друг другом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть два ряда по 3 блока:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row1">
   <div class="block1>1</div>
   <div class="block2>2</div>
   <div class="block3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
   <div class="block4">4</div>
   <div class="block5">5</div>
   <div class="block6">6</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Изначально, `row2` скрыт. Нужно, чтобы эти ряды через время подменяли друг друга. Т.е. сначала показывается `row1`, через 5 сек `row1` исчезает и его заменяет `row2`. Потом `row2` исчезает через 5 сек и его заменяет `row1`
И так нужно чтобы повторялось в цикле(бесконечно).
Как это проделать на **JS / jQuery**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.row1, .row2').toggle();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.row2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="block1">1</div>
    <div class="block2">2</div>
    <div class="block3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="block4">4</div>
    <div class="block5">5</div>
    <div class="block6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $(".row1, .row2").toggle();
}, 5000);
```

```css
.row2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="block1">1</div>
    <div class="block2">2</div>
    <div class="block3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="block4">4</div>
    <div class="block5">5</div>
    <div class="block6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Время смотрите сами

```js
while (true) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.row1').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 1000);
  $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".row2").show('fadeIn', {}, 500)
    }, 2000);
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.row2').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 3000);
  $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".row1").show('fadeIn', {}, 500)
    }, 4000);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```